# Problems with Python MD5, SHA512 (+salt) encryption

Tags: python, md5, salt, sha, sha512

I'm trying to understand how does Linux encrypt our password on the etc/shadow file, so I've dont a new virtual 'test' user to make some test:

**user:** newuser
**password:** usrpw123
**Generated salt:** Ii4CGbr7

So the OS makes me the following line on the etc/shadow file, using a SHA512 encryptation system ($6$):    **newuser:$6$Ii4CGbr7$IOua8/oPV79Yp.BwzpxlSHjmCvRfTomZ.bhEvjZV2x5qhrvk82lZVrEtWQQej2pOWMdN7hvKwNgvCXKFQm5CB/:15069:0:99999:7:::**

Now, I take the SHA512 module from python and try this:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha512()
m.update('Ii4CGbr7'+'usrpw123')
print m.hexdigest
```

This gives me the following hash as a result:
**c73156daca3e31125ce457f1343201cc8a26400b2974440af2cc72687922b48b6631d21c186796ea2756ad987a996d2b261fe9ff3af4cc81e14c3029eac5df55**

As you can see, it's different than the other one on the /etc/shadow file, and I dont know why if I'm using the same salt+password to generate the hash.
Can someone give me a hand and explain me more or less why this happens?

And also, why does the /etc/shadow files generates a hash with some dots (.)?
Thanks

Comment: Note that the hexdigest only includes `[0-9a-f]` characters, while the line in the `shadow` file is `[0-9a-zA-Z/.]`, so the output formats are different to begin with...

Comment: SHA is not an encryption system. SHA is a hashing function. There's a big difference between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fields in /etc/shadow are not built or interpreted the way you think they are.  You'll want to read the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/crypt.3.html#NOTES) for details, but the most obvious difference is that it uses an unusual base64 encoding for both the salt and the hash.

Comment: So do you know any code can I use to emulate the encryptation of MD5/SHA512 on Python? I would like to make a funcion that makes the same exit as the one of the /etc/shadow file. <br> Thanks again

Comment: @Borja: One literally need to translate from C-code into Python to achieve this. Nobody cares, as one can call system library directly from Python. Perhaps somebody has written a bridge library similar to [`crypt()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) call.

Answer (score 6):

There is an algorithm for generating the password hashes found in /etc/shadow.

See this document for an explanation:
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

There's an implementation of this in python here:
http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.html

Answer (score 2):

I fell into the same trap as everything that I read lead me to believe you could retrieve the results the same way you have it written.

I was able to determine the password by using the salt and password using crypt.crypt()

```
import crypt
crypt.crypt(password, salt)
```

salt: $6$Ii4CGbr7
password: usrpw123

doesn't exactly use the hashlib library but it works.